# Stackoverflow error (infinite loop) while using Devexpress VCL 13.1.2

Tags: delphi, devexpress, vcl

I am using `TcxGridDBBandedTableView` and have two columns of type `TcxGridDBBandedColumn`.

```
vwABC : TcxGridDBBandedTableView
vwABCField1 : TcxGridDBBandedColumn
vwABCField2 : TcxGridDBBandedColumn
```

When I change anything in vwABCField1, vwABCField2 values should get cleared. For this I am using `OnEditValueChanged` property of vwABCField1 like this:

```
procedure TMyForm.vwABCField1PropertiesEditValueChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  vwABCField2.EditValue := '';
end;
```

While debugging, when I come to `vwABCField2.EditValue := '';` statement, I never return back and get trapped in infine loop and after some time I get stackoverflow error.

`vwABCField2.EditValue := '';` is calling `vwABCField1PropertiesEditValueChanged` procedure again and again recursively infinite time. I don't know why. I have not declared anything on `OnEditValueChanged` event of `vwABCField2`.

**Update**

If I write anything else in the above function instead of `vwABCField2.EditValue := '';`, it will be called only once. For example

```
procedure TMyForm.vwABCField1PropertiesEditValueChanged(Sender:TObject); 
begin   
  ShowMessage("hi"); 
end;
```

works fine. So I suspect that culprit is `vwABCField2.EditValue := '';` statement.

Comment: @StefanGlienke - Yes I checked. vwABCField1PropertiesEditValueChanged method is getting called again and again.

Comment: You should see where it comes from the 2nd time as you said that should not happen

Comment: **Stackoverflow error** shocked

Comment: What is `Properties` (TextEdit, Memo, ...?) of your `vwABCField1` and `vwABCFField2`?

Comment: @StefanGlienke - It is LookupCombobox

Comment: A question about a Stack Overflow on StackOverflow always makes me smile (:

Comment: In the debugger, when breaking on `vwABCField2.EditValue := '';`, check all the events of `vwABCField2`. Then check if `vwABCField2` is not bound to `vwABCField1` in any way and vice versa.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers - These are not binded in any way.

Comment: Maybe the change to vwABCField2 forces some kind of update to the database and then all fields all traversed and another Change() is triggered. Look at the call stack, trace the DevEx code, make a reproducable case to post in the DevEx forums.

Comment: And have you searched the DevEx forums for 'stack overflow'? Could this be related: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q523958

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the official documentation is stated:

> Do not change the edit value in your OnEditValueChanged event handler, as this can result in stack overflow. Use this event to get notification that the edit value has changed.

Because when you change the edit value in this event, of course, your editvalue is changed and therefore calling the OnEditValueChanged event again and again and ...

Comment: Then where should I change the edit values of other cells in that row?  What should I do in my case? Also, can you provide the link for this documentation?

Comment: This documentation should be available in your IDE Help, even context sensitive.  Go to your Delphi Help and lookup the 'ExpressQuantumGrid Suite' topic in the contents tab.

Comment: And about the question on where to change other values: you better do that on the dataset side, the datasets 'onchange' or 'beforepost' event e.g.

Comment: When I add editvalue code in dsABCBeforePost, again I get trapped in the infinite loop resulting to stackoverflow.

Comment: You should not use the editvalue code for this purpose, but better change the datasets field value.

Comment: I added all the editvalue code into the dsABCField1OnChange event and it worked. Thanks for your suggestions Copilot :)